# Optimize image using mini-magick and carrierwave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I am using `carrierwave` for uploading image. Now I want to optimize images also. Like if user upload image of any size , I want to optimize that image in less 200kb size.

For that I add `mini-magick` gem.
Here is my code

```
version :listing_main do
  image = ::MiniMagick::Image::read(File.binread(@file.file))
  // Want to compress image here      
  resize_to_fill 800,600
end
```

Issue is that how I can compress image , not find any way and tutorial for that

Comment: Please refer this https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Specify-the-image-quality

Comment: With imagemagick I'm using `image.resize_to_fit(x,x)` (keeps aspect ratio), then check the the file size and resize again if greater than 200kb. I did not find a better way. But maybe there is.

Comment: Would be best if you optimized from the client side so that you can maintain fast uploads and use fewer network resources. This may be useful but I haven't tested it. https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/xor3L8db/

Comment: @CannonMoyer i already done that but also want to compress image in backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the image quality using Mini Magick and CarrierWave is simple.

First, go to the file: `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`. If not exists, create one. Put the code:

```
module CarrierWave
    module MiniMagick
        def quality(percentage)
            manipulate! do |img|
                img.quality(percentage.to_s)
                img = yield(img) if block_given?
                img
            end
        end
    end
end
```

After that, go to your image_uploader file. In my case, it is in `app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb`

```
version :listing_main do    
    process resize_to_fill: [800, 600]
    process :quality => 70
end
```

I'm using exactly this code and it works fine.

Comment: so you are changing the size and then making it 70% of its original quality, but that is not setting a maximum of 200kb as mentioned in the question. Is that possible? or does it not matter if you use resize_to_fill, Is it because `[800,600]` will always produce a smaller than 200ox image.

I notice we can get the filesize of the image,  `MiniMagick::Image.open(file.path).data["filesize"]` and it gives a string like `2.932MB` or `23.6KB` so would I need to interpret that string into an integer of KB first, checking for 'MB' or 'KB' (or maybe 'GB') to determine the percentage quality?

Comment: to add to last comment, I just noticed `process resize_to_limit: [700, 700]` changed the size of a 4 MB picture to about 140KB.. so maybe a max size is unnecessary afterall.

Comment: This solution is working for jpg/jpeg format but not for png

Comment: What is `version :listing_main do    ` ?

Where is 'listing_main' defined?

Comment: `listing_main` is the version of the image which be saved. You can have multiple versions of one uploaded image. In that case, an image will be saved with prefix `listing_main` and size 800x600 and quality 70. You are free to define any versions of the uploaded image.